# Family of Morse functions made constant

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, homology-cohomology, morse-theory

I'm looking for a proof of the following theorem:

Let $f_t$ be a family of real-valued Morse functions defined on a smooth compact manifold $M$, and where $t$ is in $[0,1]$ (So for all value of $t$, $f_t$ is Morse). Also, $f_t$ depends smoothly on $t$.  Then, it is possible to find $\phi_t$ a family of diffeomorphism on $M$, and $\psi_t$ a family of diffeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}$, with $t$ in $[0,1]$ such that, $\phi_t$ and $\psi_t$ depends smoothly on $t$, and $\forall t \in [0,1] \psi_t \circ f_t \circ \phi_t = f_0$.

Does anyone know where to find a proof of this result?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Or if you think of a proof, that's good too ;)

Comment: Presumably, $f_t$ depends smoothly on $t$?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not mentionning it

Comment: For $M = \mathbb{R}$, take $f_t(x) = x^2 - tx^4$. Then $f_t$ is Morse for all $t$, but there exists no diffeomorphism $\phi_t$ with $f_0 = f_t \circ \phi_t$; for small $\epsilon > 0$, the preimage $\#f_t^{-1}(\epsilon) = 4$ for $t\not = 0$ but $\#f_0^{-1}(\epsilon) = 2$. Although $M$ isn't compact, I think the same construction works locally for an arbitrary smooth, compact manifold. (For example, consider a small bump function, and use the fact that Morse functions are dense in $C^\infty(M)$).

Comment: Thank you very much for the example, that kind of bothers me that you're right though!

Comment: anomaly: But $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact. The critical points at $\pm 1/(2t)$ "come from infinity".

Comment: That is true Thomas Rot. I've checked and I think this theorem doesn't work if the manifold isn't compact. I've asked a prof who is sure that there is a version of the theorem, but with an additional transformation:

$\psi_t \circ f_t \circ \phi_t = f_0$

Unfortunately he can't tell where I could find the result for sure... So, any help would be very welcomed!

Comment: @user160269 I really like this question, so I am curious for an answer (wish I could upvote it more). I deleted an answer which seems to work in the one dimensional case. It doesn't work for higher dimensions because the diffeomorphism is not close to being unique. I'll try to think of it some more

Comment: Thanks for trying Thomas. This is apparently so obvious that in the paper where I found it, the writer doesn't even bother to give an explanation. He just says it works.
Also, I know it is possible to make the function constant around the critical points. But I don't know how to do in the rest of the manifold.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but it will be too long for a comment.  It is just meant to be a intuition for why this is could (should?) be true.

First, notice that we can rewrite your statement to $f_t = \psi_t^{-1}\circ f_0 \circ \phi_t ^{-1}$. Now, what you started this question with is a family of functions $\{f_t \}_{t \in I}$ that varies smoothly with $t$. I want to make the unproven claim that smoothly varying $M$ and smoothly varying $\mathbb{R}$ is exactly what $f_t = \psi_t^{-1}\circ f_0 \circ \phi_t ^{-1}$ is doing when we move through $t\in I$ for $f_t$.

A slightly different approach, but with the same flavor, is to embed $M$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$, lets call that map $e$, and let $p$ be the projection onto the last coordinate. We can think of the Morse function, $f_t$ in the following way:

$$ M\overset{\left(e,f_{t}\right)}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{R}^{n}\times\mathbb{R}\overset{p}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{R}
  $$

Then for each $t$ we have an embedding into Euclidean space such that the Morse function is projection onto the $(n+1)$-st axis. We know that $(e,f_t)$ is an smooth embedding since $M$ is compact and Euclidean space is Hausdorff. Then we can visualize the homotopy of our Morse functions as homotopy of our embedded $M$ with projection. The problem is this: do we know that homotopy of Morse functions preserves the level sets? I.e. Can we somehow have two critical points move past each other or possibly introduce a new critical point that will split a level set?  I am not sure, but I think there is a proof in here somewhere. Maybe someone who knows their differential topology better than I can give a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

I  actually just found in the past days a proof given on the blog of a maths prof! It's a bit long to put it all here, plus the prof did all the job. Here's a link to the proof:

https://euclidlab.org/research/david-gays-blog?start=4

Thanks all for the help!